# Is there any way to bind angular animation to structural directive

Tags: angular7, angular-directive, angular-animations

### I've created simple 'slider' structural directive in angular.

### Is there any way to make it alive with animations, how can I bind some animation to my private `next()` and `prev()` functions so when the user clicks `next` or `prev` content will smoothly go aside and a new content will appear, or something in that kind.

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[_slide]'
})

export class CustomSlideDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ){}

  private index: number = 0;
  private context: any;

  @Input('_slideFrom') items: any[];

  
  ngOnInit(){   
    this.context = {
      $implicit: this.items[this.index],
      next: () => this.next(),
      prev: () => this.prev(),
    }      
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef,this.context)
  }


  private next(){
    this.index++
    if(this.index === this.items.length)this.index = 0
    this.context.$implicit = this.items[this.index]
  }

  private prev(){
    this.index--
    if(this.index === -1)this.index = this.items.length - 1
    this.context.$implicit = this.items[this.index]
  }

}
```

## Here is the link to stackblitz live demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4aeg4